# jQuery prepend unexpected identifier without line breaks

Tags: jquery

I want to prepend an `html` *snippet* dynamically to another `div` using **jQuery** `append` function, but l'm getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
$( ".portlet" )
    .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all" )
    .find( ".portlet-header" )
    .addClass( "ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" )
    .prepend( "<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");
```

I'm getting this error ***`"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"`***.

I know that in general this happens from line breaks, but as you can see there are no line breaks at all.

I attached some images of the error in *chrome*:

1. Here:

   [image: here]
2. And here:

[image: bbb]

Comment: The posted snippet doesn't have any syntax error.

Comment: Please look at the edit

Comment: @GingerHead mismatching quotes: `.prepend( "<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle"></span>");` Instead use your posted code

Comment: it's really funny in the editor I have just that, it's changing after the deploy somehow ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you are "breaking" the string in the last command. The "Unexpected identifier" is the `ui-icon`, since you closed the apostrophe before it. You need start with `'` or `"`, and can't use them in the middle of the string, if you do, the string will break. So, the correct is:

```
.prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle"></span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the editor it's just like that, after deployment the inner single quotes were changing to double quotes.

So I just changed it to the following and it worked:

```
.prepend( '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle"></span>');
```

I'm using:

- Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.6.3.SR1 **`as ide`**
- Pivotal tc ServerDeveloper Editon v3.0 **`as server`**